# Nginx & React - How to have multiple containers accessible with different domains?

Tags: reactjs, docker, nginx, docker-compose

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '3.8'

services:
  stage:
    container_name: xxx-website-stage
    image: registry.gitlab.com/xxx/website:latest
    build:
      context: .
      target: stage
      dockerfile: Dockerfile

  master:
    container_name: xxx-website-master
    image: registry.gitlab.com/xxx.us/website:latest
    build:
      context: .
      target: master
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
```

**staging.xxx.us.conf**

```
upstream staging-xxx-us {
  server xxx-website-stage:3001;
}

server {

  listen 80;
  listen [::]:80;

  server_name staging.xxx.us

  root /var/www/staging.xxx.us/public_html;

  index index.html index.htm;

  location / {
    proxy_pass         http://staging-xxx-us;
    proxy_set_header    X-Real-IP           $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
    proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Host    $host;
    proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Port    $server_port;
  }
}
```

Nginx throws 500 and 502. I want to access `http://xxx.us` which is `xxx-website-master` container and `http://staging.xxx.us` which is `xxx-website-stage` container.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed the issue using [nginx-proxy](https://github.com/nginx-proxy/nginx-proxy). If you need help, please [check this out](https://github.com/nginx-proxy/nginx-proxy/issues/1472). I wrote the working configuration over there.